# What is the scope of a singularity pattern class? (Multi-Threading involved)

Tags: c#, multithreading, scope

For a project I am working on I'm implementing a class as a singularity. The class is responsible for detecting what stage (Dev, Test, Production, etc.) the system is running in, and returning certain values accordingly so our dev team won't have to worry about handling staging settings every time they use those values. In addition, it allows us to override what the stage is currently, for the purpose of pretending to be in a different stage.

My concern has to deal with how the singularity will behave when multi-threading is involved. The code below outlines the basic setup that will be used.

My question is, if program & program2 could be running on different threads at the same time, will the OverrideStage() function (which changes a private variable in the instance) interfere with the other program's expected behavior?

Example:

1) Program starts, sets stage to DEV

2) On another thread, Program2 starts, sets stage to PRODUCTION

3) Back in Program, try to get a value, will the value be in DEV or PRODUCTION?

```
namespace TESTING
{

class Program
{
    static void Run()
    {

        Staging stage = Staging.Instance;

        stage.OverrideStage(Staging.DEV);
            SqlConnection connDev = new SqlConnection(stage.ConnectionString("example")); // Connection to development database
            // Do Stuff
        stage.EndOverride();
            SqlConnection connBackToAuto = new SqlConnection(stage.ConnectionString("example")); // Connection to detected stage database
    }
}

class Program2
{             
    static void Run()
    {
        Staging s = Staging.Instance;
        s.OverrideStage(Staging.PRODUCTION);
            SqlConnection connDev = new SqlConnection(s.ConnectionString("example")); // Connection to production database
            // Do stuff
        s.EndOverride();
    }
}

} // End namespace
```

I guess the question can be simplified to:

**Are s and stage the same instance of Staging?**

Comment: the answer depends on the implementation of Staging.Instance property which you didn't include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I don't believe your application can have two main entry points... what you're describing is not feasible, unless you specify multiple entry points.</strike>

Now, if it were feasible (i.e. you specified multiple entry points), then

Your attempt to change the `Staging` mode will result in updating the mode for both program instances.

So let's look at your example:

```
1) Program starts, sets stage to DEV    
2) On another thread, Program2 starts, sets stage to PRODUCTION
3) Back in Program, try to get a value, will the value be in DEV or PRODUCTION?
```

The value will most likely be `PRODUCTION`, however it may not be the case depending on how the threads started. It can get complicated, because if both threads are started relatively quickly one after the other, then the stage might be `DEV` or `PRODUCTION` depending on when the context switch happened between the two threads.

### Update 1.0

Since strike out the multiple entry points because you've substituted `Main` methods with `Run` methods.

### Update 2.0

**To Singleton or not to Singleton**

The situation you're describing is very confusing, mainly because a Program usually contains the `Main` entry point for your application. Under normal circumstances, one would expect that the program either runs in `DEV` or `PRODUCTION` mode. Running multiple program instances in separate threads and in different modes is very confusing!!! **I can't think of a realistic example where anybody would want to do that.**

Let's suppose there was such an obscure example tho: your best bet is to provide each program with its own internal staging state, rather than a global (Singleton) staging state. This guarantees that you can start multiple instances of your program in multiple threads and each one would run independently of each-other. You generally want to share as little between threads as possible- some people refer to it as [shared nothing architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture).

**What's the staging mode?**

If you take the Singleton approach, then this question becomes very difficult to answer.

- If you have a way to guarantee that the thread running `Program2` waits for `Program` to get initialized (via some sort of [thread signalling mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696052/thread-signaling-basics)), then you're guaranteed that the mode will be `PRODUCTION`.
- If you don't have a thread signalling mechanism, then the mode might either be `DEV` or `PRODUCTION` depending on many issues.

You can, indeed, create a separate `Staging` classes in different namespaces and each one is used depending on the mode you're utilizing. However, that is no different than maintaining two separate Staging classes i.e. `DevStaging` and `ProductionStaging`. You generally want to avoid coding the same thing twice, so this option is starting to look less and less desirable.

In general, the issue of knowing which staging mode you're currently in is actually not so much to do with threading, the problem is just magnified when threading is involved. The reason why your `Staging` mode will change is because both programs use the same staging instance, which is provided to them by the Staging (singleton) instance.

Comment: Sorry about the main() confusion, I switched it to Run(), assume Run() is called to start the code there.

Comment: Then @Lirik told you exactly what may happen ans s and stage will be the same instances (assuming it's a thread safe singleton) but you can never know which thread will set it first and which one will set the stage second.

Comment: @Lirik That makes sense, however is it because they are within the same namespace? If so, my choices would be either to not use singularity pattern or move each program to its own namespace correct? If not, I'll just scrap the singularity pattern.

Comment: You're giving us a bit of an odd example. You're implying that your entire application will be run from two separate threads in two different modes. You should either start your application in `DEV` mode or `PRODUCTION` mode, I don't understand why you need to run the same application in multiple modes at the same time.

Comment: @AndrewHagner - The whole point of the *singleton* pattern is that all consumers of this type get a reference to the same, single instance.  If that is not the desired behavior, why make it a singleton?

Comment: Just scrap the singularity pattern... I'll update my answer to reflect what I mean a little better.

Comment: @Lirik The point of the staging class is to avoid having to start the code up in one specific mode. I don't show all the functionality here, but the point is it allows us to move the project around between our Dev, Test, and Prod servers without having to go in and change any settings in the project code itself every time we move it. Thus when writing code, we don't have to sit there and write a switch each time we connect to a database saying case(prod)..., case(dev)... Instead we just use Staging to handle that.

Comment: @mbeckish Originally I didn't plan for it to be used in a multi-threaded sense, and we only needed one instance per project. However we have an engine that runs classes on threads, which is what I was kinda trying to explain above. I wasn't sure if each class would be accessing the same Staging instance or if because they are different classes it would initialize a new one.

Comment: And yes, scraping the singularity pattern seems like the right way to go.

Comment: @AndrewHagner I would imagine that the point of the **singleton** staging class **should** be to maintain the global state of the application, depending on which mode it's started in. If you try to start the application in two modes, then a non-singleton staging class would be what you would actually want to use.

Comment: I know its a confusing situation lol, Simply put, we have a service, that runs independent business rules (classes) at independent intervals (hence multi-threading). Due to a limited environment, we may run the service on the dev server, but want one rule to be acting like it's in test, while another runs as if it's train, etc... Odd, yes, but not unrealistic :)

Comment: To make it more confusing, we'd be using it in the service I mentioned, but also in other projects where it **would** be maintaining the global state, in that case I could get away with the singularity, but like you said, not in the case with multi-threading. Thanks!