# semaphores C# Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I was trying to follow a piece of pseudo-code having to do with Semaphores and when I translated the code to C# I'm getting the error in the title.

After some research, the error is happening because I'm calling `cust_ready.ReleaseMutex()` without calling `cust_ready.WaitOne()` within the same thread. The problem is that this is exactly what the pseudo-code is doing so I'm not sure how to resolve this?

`cust_ready.WaitOne()` is called but in a separate thread, below is the pseudo code in question:

**Thread1:**

> wait(mutex2);
>
> enqueue(custnr);
>
> **signal(cust_ready);**
>
> signal(mutex2);

**Thread2:**

> **wait(cust_ready);**
>
> wait(mutex2);
>
> dequeuel(b_cust);
>
> signal(mutex2);

and this is my C# code:

**Thread1:**

> mutex2.WaitOne();
>
> customerQueue.Enqueue(custnr);
>
> **cust_ready.ReleaseMutex();**
>
> mutex2.ReleaseMutex();

**Thread2:**

> **cust_ready.WaitOne();**
>
> mutex2.WaitOne();
>
> var exists = customerQueue.TryDequeue(out var b_cust);
>
> mutex2.ReleaseMutex();

Comment: cust_ready is not a mutex.  Producer-consumer support is readily available in .NET, use ConcurrentQueue or BlockingCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutex is an object to synchronize access to resources and you use it to protect customerQueue. On the other hand, mutex is not designed to signal something. To signal you can use AutoResetEvent as cust_ready.

**Thread1**

```
mutex2.WaitOne();
customerQueue.Enqueue(custnr);
cust_ready.Set();
mutex2.ReleaseMutex();
```

**Thread2**

```
cust_ready.WaitOne();
mutex2.WaitOne();
var exists = customerQueue.TryDequeue(out var b_cust);
mutex2.ReleaseMutex();
```

Similar topic [Thread signaling basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696052/thread-signaling-basics)

[AutoResetEvent documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.8) - remarks section mentions other objects which can be used to signal between threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [ConcurrentQueue Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8).

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentQueue are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.